# Code organization in JavaScript: MVC? Self-rendering components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, components, code-organization

I'm building an extremely JS-heavy web application. I say it's JS-heavy, because the vast majority of the work going on is done on the client (although there is some syncing back and forth to the server using AJAX and XMPP).

This is my first time building something of this scale in pure JS (using jQuery), so I began by organizing my code using MVC in a manner modeled after Rails. For example, if the user clicks a button, a method is called in the Controller object, which pulls some data from the models, and which then passed the data a view function. I do this for pretty much everything, even trivial actions like showing a small popup.

After a few months of this, I feel like I'm not taking full advantage of the language. Should I really be rendering my views as if they are webpages?

It seems like it'd make more sense to break down the views into components, which would be instances of Javascript objects/functions. For example, instead of...

```
var itemListHTML = '<ul id="item-list"><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul>';
jQuery('#container').html(itemListHTML);
```

...I could instead have...

```
components.itemList.render();
```

So here, there's just a component called `itemList`. Since all the data is stored on the client, these components could instantly access all of the data necessary to create and manage themselves. I imagine I would still use MVC, but there'd be no need for controller actions that are responsible for the entire view. If I want to refresh one part of the UI, I just call `whateverComponentControlsThatArea.redraw()` and it re-renders itself.

I'm sure someone had done this before. Is there a name for this style of code organization? Any guides or best-practices for how to implement it?

Comment: Have you seen backbone.js? http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: Reading about it now, looks great so far

Comment: It's difficult to tell what your real question is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of javascript MVC frameworks available now
[JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/), [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/), [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) for example.
Rendering of views or sub-views in normally handled through some kind of templating engine.
JavaScriptMVC has a module [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/), which is modelled on ERB, which I have found quite useful. Templates can be compiled into functions to speed things up for production.
There are other templating solutions too for example John [Resig's Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) and [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend)

I recommend you use one of these frameworks if it's not too late. I've used JavaScriptMVC for a few projects now and can recommend it (The docs take some getting used to though)

Answer (score 2):

You should really look into jquery.tmpl (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) for creating fast javascript templating ideal for building your view rendering.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I've got $0.02 here that I'm not sure what to do with...

Forgetting about (typical) Web-MVC (ie: RailsMVC, et cetera) for a second:

Consider that JavaScript can all be resident in the same place, and that you don't have to worry about figuring out routing and class-instantiating (unless you really want to).

Ideally, from a software point of view, what you want MVC to do is to separate what the user does, from what makes up the content (based on the action), from what makes up the view (based on the action).

There's nothing saying that you can't have multiple views, or even that you can't have a view which contains multiple views (which might use templates, or be functionally generated, and attached to a DOM-node - either is valid).

In a simple pseudo-example, rather than having a flow that looks like:

Action Loads Controller -> Controller Loads Model -> Controller Queries Model -> Model Answers Controller -> Controller Loads View -> Controller Feeds Data to View -> View Sends Page to Controller -> Controller Outputs Page

Why not something like:

Controller Listens for Action (addEventListener) -> Controller Turns Action into State-Logic -> Controller Notifies Model (observer) OR Model Polls Controller -> Model Changes State based on Logic, and Collects / Sorts all Data -> Model Notifies View (observer) OR View Polls Model -> View Changes State based on Logic -> View Renders all Components, based on Data + ViewState (innerHTML OR documentFragment).

It looks a little longer, but in reality, everything is nice and separate.
With the View (or View Manager or however you want to think of it) dictating what windows are on the page, and how each window is made up, and where the data goes, inside of each article, in each window...

...now you have an MVC pattern, but you ALSO have the ability to say:

```
View["mainpage"] = {

    data : { tweets : [{id:...}...]/* et cetera - pushed by Model, not Controller */ },
    layout : [ "Header", "Carousel", "Articles", "TwitterFeed", "RSSFeed", "Footer" ],

    // if your system is this clean, you could even prototype the content-builders
    // rather than defining them in each ViewState - you'd just need layout, then
    buildPage : function () {
        var page = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (/* everything in this.layout */) {
            View.build[this.layout[i]](this.data, page);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(page);
    },

    cleanUp : function () { /* fancy or simple DOM cleaning for state-change */ },

    // grabs SubView by expected handle (id="tweetfeed" or whatever) and replaces it
    // observer functionality, for views to automatically update as data changes
    updateView : function (view, newData) { ... },

    addData : function (data) { this.data = data; }, // for Observer

    /* Observer - if you want to run the WHOLE site with AJAX from index.html
     * clean up old (ex:"main") page and build and/or transition new (ex:"media") page
     * could be unique for each page, for custom transitions, or just prototype it */
    changeState : function (newState, newData) {
        View["mainpage"].cleanUp();
        View[newState].addData( newData );
        View[newState].buildPage();
    }
}
```

And now you've defined your whole main-page.
Of course, it's going to be extra work maintaining not only definitions for your main page, but for every page/section.
...and then, you need to make the functions which will create each sub-view -- but component-based design is EXACTLY what you were asking about.
In essence, for each widget, it will have its own building-logic.
That's what views do - they either have an individual template that gets reused, or they have a function that works the same way every time.

And an atomic view is one where you're dealing with a function that builds 1 item (1 Tweet, 1 Post, 1 Store item) and builds the view for that.
Having a Single_Tweet view post a single-tweet to the page, 20 times in a row would be a **bad** idea for JS performance.

But having a Single_Tweet view push tweets, in order, into a Tweets array that your Twitter_Feed view puts on the site is A-OK.

Even better is when your Pages are Views, made up of Widgets of Views, made up of Atomic-Units of Views.
And when all of that happens off-DOM (so innerHTML or documentFragment).

And the best would be a Framework where you define pages in this way, but you can also update an individual Widget, based on data-pushes from the Model, whenever you want.

And that's the beauty of AJAX -- old-fashioned MVC can happen, without a Controller that knows everything.

The Controller just holds a list of pressed-keys, the mouse coordinates, a clicked button's intent...
And it tells the Model that something happened.
The Model does everything state/data/data-manipulation (sorting) related, and feeds the new state or data to the view, which takes it all and puts it into HTML, in the order you specify.

That's about it.